# If(statement) delay

Tags: java, android, if-statement, time, delay

This is a curiosity question but is there a way to delay the final line in an if statement.

eg:

```
if(m_Toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISBILE) {
               ...........
    m_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How would you go about delaying the final line like (ie.GONE)?

Comment: What do you mean with delay? Usually ``Thread.sleep`` will cause a delay but I'm sure that's not what you want here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.sleep` will cause UI to freeze , I suggest to use `Handler` instead

```
if(m_Toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISBILE) {
    ...........
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }, 3000);//3 seconds
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Please **DO NOT** use `Thread.Sleep()` that will freeze the UI Use a `Handler`

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        },delayMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` which waits for one second.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(m_Toolbar.getVisibility() == View.VISBILE) {
        
        int Delay = 5;  //set Your request delay
        
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  
                 do{
                      try {
                          
                          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                              public void run() {
                                                                  
                                  Delay --;
                                  
                                  if( Delay == 0){
                                      
                                      m_Toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                  }
                                      
                              }
                          });   
                          
                          Thread.sleep(1000);
                          
                           
                      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                          //TODO Auto-generated catch block
                          e.printStackTrace();
                      } 

                  }while(Delay > 0);

               }
          }).start();
        
    }
```

Comment: Rolled back because first half was copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/48326340/4294399